# Hibernate reloading entities in a fetch join

Tags: java, hibernate, join

I am having a problem with Hibernate reloading the entities in a query even though they are being fetched as part of the main query.

The entities are as follows (simplified)

```
class Data {
    @Id
    String guid;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    DataContents contents; 
}

class DataClosure {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ancestor_id", nullable = false)
    private Data ancestor;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JoinColumn(name = "descendant_id", nullable = false)
    private Data descendant;

    private int length;
}
```

This is modelling a closure table of parent / child relationships.

I have set up some criteria as follows

```
    final Criteria criteria = getSession()
            .createCriteria(DataClosure.class, "dc");
    criteria.createAlias("dc", "a");
    criteria.createAlias("dc.descendant", "d");
    criteria.setFetchMode("a", FetchMode.JOIN);
    criteria.setFetchMode("d", FetchMode.JOIN);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("d.metadataGuid",guidParameter));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.ne("a.metadataGuid",guidParameter));
```

This results in the following SQL query

```
select
    this_.descendant_id as descenda2_21_2_,
    this_.ancestor_id as ancestor3_21_2_,
    this_.length as length1_21_2_,
    d2_.guid as metadata1_20_0_,
    d2_.name as name5_20_0_,
    a1_.guid as metadata1_20_1_,
    a1_.name as name6_20_1_
from
    data_closure this_ 
inner join
    data d2_ 
        on this_.descendant_id=d2_.metadata_guid 
inner join
    data a1_ 
        on this_.ancestor_id=a1_.metadata_guid 
where
    d2_.guid=? 
    and a1_.guid<>?
```

which looks like it is correctly implementing the join fetch. However when I execute

```
    List list = criteria.list();
```

I see one of these entries in the SQL log per row in the result set

```
Result set row: 0
DEBUG Loader  - Loading entity: [Data#testGuid19]
DEBUG SQL  - 
select
    data0_.guid as guid1_20_0_,
    data0_.title as title5_20_0_,
from
    data data0_ 
where
    data0_.guid=?
Hibernate: 
   (omitted)
DEBUG Loader  - Result set row: 0
DEBUG Loader  - Result row: EntityKey[Data#testGuid19]
DEBUG TwoPhaseLoad  - Resolving associations for [Data#testGuid19]
DEBUG Loader  - Loading entity: [DataContents#7F1134F890A446BBB47F3EB64C1CF668]
DEBUG SQL  - 
select
    dataContents0_.guid as guid_12_0_,
    dataContents0_.isoCreationDate as isoCreat2_12_0_,
from
    dataContents dataContents0_ 
where
    dataContents0_.guid=?
Hibernate: 
    (omitted)
```

It is looks like even though the DataContents is marked as lazily loaded, it's being loaded eagerly.

So I either want some way in my query to fetch join DataClosure and Data and lazily fetch DataContents, or to fetch join the DataContents if that is not possible.

Edit:

Modelling the closure table like this

```
class DataClosure {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ancestor_id", nullable = false, length =36 )
    private String ancestorId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "descendant_id", nullable = false, length =36 )
    private String descendantId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ancestor_id", nullable = false)
    private Data ancestor;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JoinColumn(name = "descendant_id", nullable = false)
    private Data descendant;

    private int length;
}
```

fixed the problem. In other words, having @Id annotation on entities from other tables seemed to cause the issue, even though there was nothing wrong with the queries generated.

Comment: And you're sure that your code isn't triggering the loading of `DataContents`?

Comment: Yes, I just did this from a breakpoint before and after calling the list() method, so my code hadn't had a chance to do anything yet.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem here might be this

```
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
```

There are plenty of google results where using that causes the lazy loading to become eager. I think it is a bug in Hibernate.

Adding this to the list of annotations should fix the problem

```
@LazyToOne(value=LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
```

Since that informs Hibernate that you will not try to use that property later on so no proxy is required.

Comment: That almost worked, it cut down a lot of the queries for the DataContents, but I'm still getting one query per Data entity, which should have been loaded via the fetch join.

Comment: Were you able to confirm that the NotFound annotation is the reason though? So if you remove it completely what happens?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I've actually simplified the entity model so that I have got rid of the DataContents entity, and I've just got a regular column in there now (String type). I'm *still* getting one query for the Data entity per returned row, even though the join query is being executed correctly.

Comment: I figured it out - it was the @Id column I was using. It was an entity  so for some reason Hibernate won't accept that as a fetch join candidate. I'll edit my question to show the solution.

Comment: Oh. Glad that you were able to solve it but this seems yet again like some Hibernate quirk that should not be there :)